# Logitech G700 mouse scrollwheel is way too sensitive, how can I configure it?

Tags: mouse, logitech, scrolling, xinput

I am trying to migrate my brother to use Ubuntu.

However, his Logitech G700 mouse's scroll wheel is extremely sensitive.

By sensitive, I mean that, due to the fact that it uses high-resolution scrolling, every minor nudge is interpreted as a scroll attempt.

I have no way to configure this in Ubuntu - I want the OS to ignore every few events from the mouse scroll wheel to make it work properly. `xev` in a terminal is going crazy whenever I even lay a finger on the scroll wheel.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Logitech G700, but here's what I did for my Perixx MX-2000, maybe it's something like that for you too :

- Perixx delivered my mouse with a CD-ROM containing the software to configure it's buttons, sensibility, LED and Macro's
- I installed this software on a Windows Operating System and plugged my mouse in.
- I configured everything through the Perixx Software
- Once I was sure that my mouse did exactly what I wanted it to do, I unplugged it.

Now, everything is configured inside the mouse, so I don't need the software anymore. When I plug it in Ubuntu, MacOS or Windows, everything I choose is working.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark but you might have some luck from tweaking your 'input device protocols' as described here :: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

If he likes windows a suitable option might be "Microsoft"