# 15.04 Logitech M325 scroll wheel is too sensitive

Tags: 15.04, mouse, logitech

The scroll wheel of logitech M325 mouse became very sensitive, I noticed it few weeks ago, so it is probably caused by driver update. It is enough to put my finger on scroll wheel and it scrolls the page.

On Windows I haven't noticed such problem. So there is not problem with mouse.

Can you please advise me what can I do with it?

this question is different from [How can I adjust the mouse scroll speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed) because it relates to ubuntu 15.04 with package `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` already installed

Comment: Have you tried multiple answers on that question ? Particularly this http://askubuntu.com/a/259628/295286 ?

Answer (score 4):

`xinput list-props 9`, where 9 is device id, shows `"Evdev Scrolling Distance"`  property, which was set to `1 1 1` by default.

I solved the problem with following command, which sets first number to higher one and makes scroll wheel less sensitive

```
xinput set-prop 9 "Evdev Scrolling Distance" 3 1 1
```