# How to increase mouse scrolling speed on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I was trying to increase my mouse scrolling speed, I follow this guide [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916647/how-to-fix-microsoft-mouse-scrolling-speed-on-ubuntu), but when I type this line:

x is 10 in this case

> $ xinput list-props 10 | grep 'Scrolling Distance'

I didn't get this line as result:

> `Evdev Scrolling Distance (255): 1, 1, 1`

And then I continued & type this line:

> $ xinput set-prop 10 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 10, 10, 10

And it said:

```
property 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Is there some package that I need to install first? thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, hopefully someone will be able to answer this for you.  On another note, I have deleted my now obsolete comments.  You can too if you want.  Cheers.