# Mouse scroll problem

Tags: scrolling

When I am using the mouse wheel to scroll it is very jumpy and often I am ending up on the same line or above when I try to scroll down. I have read threads about the same problem but the only solution I have seen is to unplug the mouse and plug in back in. Which did not work. 
Anyone sitting on a solution for this problem?

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: It is very possible that the problem is in the mouse hardware (optical detection of wheel movement) and not in the software. Try opening the mouse and cleaning the wheel assembly, but most likely you will need new mouse.

Comment: Have the same problem - as indicated from Ubuntu forums try playing with the command xset, the threshold and acceleration can be configured there on the command line. The best solution seems to be install synaptics. https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but what worked for me was to "kiss" the mouse scroll wheel and blow as hard as I can. I think that moved/removed some of the dust and lint inside.
Hopefully this helps someone since this is one of the first search results for this issue.

Comment: This is really funny for an answer! Who knows..?