# Mouse wheel detect all minor movement as full step

Tags: mouse

After a recent update, which included kernel upgrade, my mouse now registers a scroll action for every minor movement I make. Typically you would expect a scroll to be registered when you advance the wheel from one position to the next. Now it is registering, by my manual count, as many as 8 scroll movements when only advancing the wheel one position.

```
user@computer ~ $ uname -r
4.4.0-190-generic
```

Running Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm quite lost in how to solve an issue like this and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please specify you release (18.04 or 20.04, etc). And also the old and new kernel versions.

Comment: @AbhayPatil added Ubuntu version. Don't know the previous kernel I had though :S

Comment: do you face this problem with any other mouse than the current one? And which mouse?

Comment: also try this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/709184/1067851

Comment: @AbhayPatil I don't have any extra mouse to try with, however I do have another harddrive with Linux Mint 20 on where I use the same mouse with no issue. The mouse I use is the Logitech MX Performance. I will update the post as well.

Comment: @AbhayPatil The answer given for the link you gave doesn't apply in my case. In theory I would be fine with a mouse that scrolls too fast, but it actually registers the 8 events per scrollwheel movement. Any applications that the scroll as an action, like zooming on a map in a game or zooming in GIMP, will be unusable unless the triggers are resolved. I did try the answer though, just in case, but no luck :(

Comment: I managed to solve my issue with a "hacky" fix. I restart my mouse when the computer has started and this solves the issue until I reboot again.