# How can I increase the scroll speed of my 'Logitech K400' mouse?

Tags: mouse, logitech, scrolling

I need to increase the vertical scrolling speed of my mouse wheel. I've looked at other Q and As for this but I need help with my specific Logitech K400 mouse.

I've typed `xinput list`. My mouse is device 9 so I type `xinput list-props 9` and I get a list of options but none of them are obvious choices. I've tried a few but the vertical scrolling has not changed.

```
Device 'Logitech K400':
    Device Enabled (156):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (292):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (293):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (294):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (295): 7
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (296): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (298):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (299): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (300): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (301):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (302):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (303):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (304): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (305): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (275): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (276):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (277):    0, 0
    Device Node (278):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (279):    1133, 16459
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (306):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (307):
```

Comment: Yeah it's weird. I have a similar mouse and it seems that `xinput` simply has no way of adjusting scroll wheel sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you it for **Firefox**:

- In the address bar, navigate to `about:config`
- accept the warning about risks of powerful settings
- in the additional search bar that appears, search for:

> mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y

The default value is 100. Just to provide an example, I have it at 225.

---

**Update:**

I have found this another question on this site: [How can I adjust the mouse scroll speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)

I can't point to any Holy Grail solution in it; a lot of different approaches are offered, but a lot of them are no silver bullet.

Comment: I use Chrome. I ended up finding an extension called 'Linux Scroll Speed Fix'.