# Forward and backward mouse buttons just doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xorg, mouse

I just got a new mouse from Logitech (M720 Triathlon) yesterday. Initially, everything was working well. Today, however, without having changed anything on my system, the Forward and Backward button just stopped working. I have the exact same problem with another mouse and both work well on Windows, so it's not a hardware problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 (Linux 5.8.0) on Xorg. Of course, I've tried to test the events with `xev`. Normal buttons trigger two events when I click `xev`'s window: `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease`, each of them showing `button 1` (for left click) and so on. However, the forward and backward buttons show only three events: `LeaveNotify`, `KeymapNotify`, and `EnterNotify`.

When I left-click:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8493778, (71,177), root:(3048,529),
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8493905, (71,177), root:(3048,529),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

When I click with the forward/backward buttons (it's the same):

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8494941, (71,177), root:(3048,529),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 16

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8495038, (71,177), root:(3048,529),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 16

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967214 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The most bizarre stuff, however, starts now. If I hold down any button (except these two, of course) and, then, click with the Forward/Backward, the thing changes:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8883308, (65,122), root:(3042,474),
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8885715, (65,122), root:(3042,474),
    state 0x110, button 9, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8885813, (65,122), root:(3042,474),
    state 0x110, button 9, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x7ae, subw 0x0, time 8886525, (65,122), root:(3042,474),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

While holding any other button (`button 1`, in this case), these two *just works* (it includes browser and whatever). After noting this, I tested two other mice that I have, and both show the same behavior.

I've read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations), but it doesn't work.

Well, what I can do to get these buttons triggering events even when I'm not pressing other buttons?

Comment: Take a look also here :https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel#Edit_your_configuration_file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've realized that [`imwheel`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IMWheel) was responsible for messing things up. Apparently, it tries to remap buttons 8 and 9 to who-knows-what. Luckily, it's quite simple to tell `imwheel` to just look at some buttons. For my mouse that uses buttons 4, 5, 6, and 7 for scrolling, I just have to start `imwheel` this way:

```bsh
imwheel -b "4 5 6 7"
```

and it'll ignore all other buttons.