# How to install package xorg-server

Tags: package-management, xserver, pkg-config

I'm following this [recipe](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278266/686407) to build xf86-input-libinput from source with a patch applied.

The command `./configure --prefix=/usr` gives me an error that I haven't been able to resolve:

```
checking for xorg-server >= 1.10 xproto inputproto >= 2.2... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.10 xproto inputproto >= 2.2) were not met:

No package 'xorg-server' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XORG_CFLAGS
and XORG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I've already installed `xserver-xorg`, it's at the newest version `1:7.7+22ubuntu1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably doing a similar thing. (see error message below)
Posting a more complete and immediately useful answer

> checking for XORG... no
> configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.7 xproto inputproto ) were not met:

> No package 'xorg-server' found
> No package 'xproto' found
> No package 'inputproto' found

You can install the need dev package like so:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev

I also needed
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev

Thanks to the comment in the previous answer that you can [look up package names](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=xorg-server.pc)

Answer (score 1):

You need the *development package*, not just the runtime binary package:

```
$ dpkg -S xorg-server.pc
xserver-xorg-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/xorg-server.pc
```

Comment: `dpkg -S` will work only for already installed. Why not recommend `apt-file` or https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=xorg-server.pc ?

Comment: @N0rbert my intention wasn't really to recommend it - just to demonstrate the answer