# How to increase mouse scroll speed - explained for begginers?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I want to increase the mouse scroll wheel speed, and I found no answers for **beginners** (Ubuntu 21.04) with all the steps properly explained.

**EG:**
For example, I read a line beginning with

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel...
```

OK, so I attempt to copy paste the line into a Terminal~, but then...says to edit a file...
*Wait, what file, where can I find this file, and how do I edit it?*
**Why** don't you add the command path and the command for edit for edit task?

It would be a lot better if the indications would regard the beginner level, and even better if I could do that from Settings panel in Ubuntu.

Comment: A question without a rant is more likely to get help.

Comment: You are welcome to help improve AskUbuntu by adding your own answers with additional explanation, instruction, and detail to help beginners.

Comment: Welcome, if you want a user-friendly OS, buy a Macintosh. Or you want Ubuntu GUI to be friendly, contribute!

Comment: Sadaharu Wakisaka, I don't understand. What is happening if I make a donation, I receive an answer from you, or I get to another forum of paying members ?

Comment: @zx485 I didn't know that "i" should be written "I", ok, thanks. It relates with grammer, not with Linux. I know in Linux you must use the exact letter in Terminal.
I am not using words for granted, there are so many situations that gets someone coming from Windows, stucked in the comments section of help, that he founds on Internet.
Anyway can you or anyone help me with the mouse scroll speed?
Thank you.

Comment: @Nmath What is GNOME/KDE?
If i boot and ”try Ubuntu” what is happening next, do i have options there on memory stick for ...KDE type of Ubuntu?
Once i will be there, i will not be able to be online, i guess, so can you help me making this change ?
The (non-removal) battery is my major issue, i want to stop Laptop to charge it.

Comment: The "vanilla" flavour of Ubuntu desktop comes with the GNOME desktop environment.  Kubuntu comes with KDE which is radically different. They are both official flavors of Ubuntu and are both Ubuntu "under the hood" but provide a completely different user interface.  You create Kubuntu installation media the same way you make it for Ubuntu, except you download the Kubuntu ISO. Look at the link for the full list of flavours.  Try Ubuntu is a live session which lets you use the OS without having to install it.  And yes you can connect to your network

Comment: @Nmath thanks for the tip. Do you think Kubuntu can help me to fix this charging non stop the battery ?
Could you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To change the mouse parameters:

- list the peripherals, note the good number with the device name of the mouse!

  ```
    xinput list
  ```
- list parameters from peripheral number 9

  ```
    xinput list-props 9
  ```
- set the acceleration of peripheral 9 to value 3. The higher the value is, the more you divide the acceleration. Acceleration is maximum for a value equal to 1. The "basis" value seems to be 1.7, for me...

  ```
    xinput set-prop 9 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 3
  ```

To permanently set the change :
A hidden file in your directory is ".profile" (Ctrl+H to see hidden files)
Double click on it and open it. Copy paste the previous command at the end. That's it!

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)

Hope it will work.

Comment: Which one is mouse ?

Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                      id=6 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17             id=7 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                     id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: Is there any issue with your mouse ? because in my case it clearly shows my mouse name. May be it could be from these !   Please refer this [artical](https://linuxhint.com/change_mouse_touchpad_settings_xinput_linux/)

Comment: I do not understand what is ”xwayland- pointer”.
What can i do? (I have a Hama new mouse)
I don't see the word ”mouse” in this list.

Comment: If you are using a laptop than make sure that you have not connected your mouse to your laptop.. and if connected try to disconnect your mouse and see the IDs for the same and again try to find your mouse id..                                      And If you are using pc than disconnect your mouse and fire the command and see the changes in Ids..                           Hope it make sense !

Comment: With or without mouse, i get the same answer: https://ibb.co/6PpxJjH 
I see from that picture that ”virtual core pointer” should be the mouse.
So which one is the id: 2,4,6 or 7?

Comment: Can someone help me with this list of devices ? Which one is the mouse, and ... what is next?

Comment: My MX Master 3 did not have this option. I used Solar to disable "Wheel Resolution" instead, which lowered the scroll speed to something sensible.