# while Scrolling with 2 fingers on touch-pad contents skipped in Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I have just dual-booted windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 and I am facing a problem with scrolling on any page in Ubuntu.

Whenever I scroll down a page with the touch-pad contents get skipped or move very fast.

I have tried many things to overcome this problem like changing some settings in synaptic.

For eg: slowing down the speed of scrolling with "Synaptics Scrolling Distance " but not hopefully succeeded.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust the mouse scroll speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got some lead. For me, this is because of imwheel. when I increase the mousewheel speed through imwheel then my content start getting skipped while scrolling through touchpad.
I don't know why it is happening but making the by default imwheel speed(3) solves this problem for me.
But I am still looking for the solution through which I can increase my mousewheel speed and still the content not get skipped through touchpad.

Comment: Also happens to me. Any solution?