# Ubuntu boots to black screen on mac

Tags: 22.04, mac

might be unrelated but i was following this quide
[How to increase the speed of a mouse wheel in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393420/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-a-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu/1441416#1441416)
and after that my ubuntu keeps rebooting to a black screen is there any fix i can implement?

Comment: Is there a login prompt in the black screen?