# Decrease scroll speed with imwheel

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I've tried decreasing my mouse scroll speed with imwheel because currently it is way too high. Unfortunately, I would need to put a lesser than 1 value to have a bearable sensitivity, but it doesn't work. I can only increase my mouse scroll sensitivity by putting a greater than 1 value.

Do you know a way of doing it ? Or maybe another solution to decrease my mouse scroll sensitivity ?

PS: my ~/.imwheelrc file looks like this for know:
".*"
None, Up, Button4, 1
None, Down, Button5, 1

And I would like to do something like:
".*"
None, Up, Button4, 0.5
None, Down, Button5, 0.5

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What version of Ubuntu and the model of your mouse you have? Did you read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed) and nothing works for you?