# Mouse wheel scrolling too fast (too sensitive)

Tags: 20.04, mouse-wheel

In Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, scrolling using the mouse wheel is too fast (too sensitive).

What to do ?

Comment: check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust the mouse scroll speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)