# How to adjust touchpad scrollspeed in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

I have been using ubuntu 22.04 on my asus laptop for quite a long time now and haven't been able to find a solution to the scrollspeed issue. by default, the touchpad two finger scrollspeed is too fast.
My question is, is there a way to adjust the scroll speed back to normal? using ubuntu without a mouse is not so comforting for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust the mouse scroll speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)

Comment: No, that solution is probably for adjusting the 'mouse scroll speed' what I am looking for is how to adjust the '2 finger touchpad scroll speed'

Comment: They are the same thing, aren't they?

Comment: My Mouse works perfectly but touchpad doesn't

Comment: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: that didn't help