Mouse scrolling in 24.04 under Wayland
How can I adjust the ammount of lines the scrollwheel moves up or down, I know I have adjusted this in the past but I can't remember how. I am using 24.04 with Wayland and Gnome and have been using Wayland and Gnome for several years now Before that X and Gnome. I am using a Logitech Lift mouse under Bluetooth.

was this Q&A the one you were referring to?

@graham No, that thread deals with X11 and imwheel but imwheel does not function under Wayland.

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed

@amar Thanks, but that thread is also about a mouse under X11 and not under Wayland.
